# Is there a way of seeing how many open sessions there are in IIS6?

Tags: iis-6, web

I have a feeling we are being hit by very high traffic, how do I prove or disprove my theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use performance counters (perfmon), specifically Web Service\Current Connections

Comment: How do I add live sessions in Perfmon?

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS log files, they log every single request that comes into the server. By default, they should be located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\, however, your server administrator may have changed that

Comment: Can I analyzer them live without affecting them (as far as I can understand most text editors will have a fit as the file constantly changes)